# Show only user-created taxonomy entries

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, taxonomy

iam implementing an event system on wordpress which allows an restricted user the following:

1. Create a new organizer (custom-post-type)
2. Create an event (custom-post-type)

Creating an event the user should choose an organizer for a special event by a list. Therefore i handle the organizer cpt as a taxonomy inside the event cpt.

Now my question is:
How can i only show the organizers, which this specific user has created? I face the problem, that all existing events are shown on every event for every user.

If you need any code or screenshots let me know, thank you very much in advance!

Comment: When you list the posts have you also checked the post_author field against current user id?

Comment: Honestly i don't know in which file or function i have to make this compare to "only show" user created entries in the create event admin site. I.e. which php files create the admin view of a custom post type? I just registered a cpt with register_post_type() and the corresponding taxonomies with register_taxonomy()

Comment: So you want content in admin to be filtered based on who is logged in?

Comment: Exactly! I already got this by role restrictions. My custom author user can only do 2 things, creating organizers and events. But on event post creation he can choose of ALL organizers and not only of those he made by himself.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it with [Advanced Custom Fields](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com) plugin ([Relationship Field](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/relationship/)). It is possible to relate cpts into another cpt. I learned to **NOT** use a cpt as a taxonomy.

[Approach for filtering only user created posts](https://support.advancedcustomfields.com/forums/topic/relationship-field-user-filter/)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it by adding the following code to your functions.php file

```
function posts_for_current_author($query) {
    global $pagenow;

    if( 'edit.php' != $pagenow || !$query->is_admin )
        return $query;

    if( !current_user_can( 'edit_others_posts' ) ) {
        global $user_ID;
        $query->set('author', $user_ID );
    }
    return $query;
}
add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'posts_for_current_author');
```